# Detect RS232 lines activity

Tags: transistors, led, rs232, pnp

Trying to work out a simple LED indicator scheme for UART lines(3.3V) and wanted to know if this seemed appropriate. my signals baud rate can be vary from 9600 to 115200. I tried below circuit but not satisfied with the result.

[image]

The circuit is working but LED brightness is very low when it comes to high baud rates. How to get same brightness for low and high baud rates??

[LED datasheet](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/150060GS75000.pdf)

Need suggestions on this circuit or any better option with less components?? using micro controller is not an option.

Comment: Your **green** LED combined with Q1's base-emitter voltage consumes almost all of the 3.3V DC supply. This would work better with a +5V supply. Or a RED LED might help, by needing less forward voltage.

Answer (score 4):

You can connect the Rx/Tx lines to something like a [74VHC123AFT](http://file:///C:/Users/Spehro/Downloads/74VHC123AFT_datasheet_en_20170308.pdf) (one chip for both lines), and drive the LEDs directly with the output (preferably the /Q output with a series resistor to Vcc). Try a time in the 100ms range. LED current of a couple mA should be sufficient with a good LED.

The retriggerable multivibrator will cause the LED to illuminate continuously if the lines toggle at more than 10Hz. Once the activity disappears, the LED goes off.

Comment: I could use it but the problem is i have 20 channels and i can't use 20 of these.

Answer (score 3):

I used this circuit 4 years ago. this was working fine. Current will flow only through the LEDs when a transmission is ongoing (you see this as a "longer ON state" when transmissions are ongoing). If there is a small pause between a couple of transmissions you will see some blinking (LED turns OFF).

[image]